# symfony 1.4 validation form bind problem

Tags: forms, validation, symfony1

I have some problem with validation forms in symfony 1.4
Here is code:

```
class NormalForm extends sfForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->setWidgets(array(
      'name' => new sfWidgetFormInput(),
      'phone' => new sfWidgetFormInput(),
      'terms' => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(array('value_attribute_value' => 1, 'default' => true))
    ));

    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('results[%s]');

    $this->setValidators(array(
      'name' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true), array('required' => 'This field may not by empty')),
      'phone' => new sfValidatorNumber(array('min' => 100000000), array('required' => 'This field may not by empty','min' => 'To short','invalid' => 'Not a number')),
      'terms' => new sfValidatorBoolean(array('required' => true), array('required' => 'Accept the regulations'))
    ));
  }
}


class homeActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->nform = new NormalForm();

    $this->module_action = "/".$this->moduleName."/".$this->actionName;

$this->name = $request->getPostParameter('results[name]');
$this->phone = $request->getPostParameter('results[phone]');
$this->foo = $request->getPostParameter('results');

    if($request->isMethod('post')){
         $this->message .= 'post ';
         $this->nform->bind($request->getParameter('results'));
        if($this->nform->isValid()){
                    $this->message .= 'is valid';
        $this->save = 'save';
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This is here: http://nowa.hipotekaplus.pl

When form is valid then should this text show:

```
<h1>Zgłoszenie zarejestrowano 1</h1>
    <p>Dziękujemy za przesłanie zgłoszenia.
    Twój osobisty doradca na telefon z pewnością zadzwoni w ciągu 24 godzin (w dni robocze).
    Zgłoszenia obsługują doradcy kredytowi na telefon Hipotekaplus.pl.</p>
```

Can somebody tell me why this not work ?

Comment: What does not work? What error message are you getting?

Comment: There is no error, but when i do                                     if($this->nform->isValid()){
  $this->message .= 'is valid'; } this message is not written in template, nothing is done in this if section

Comment: Try `var_dump($this->nform->getErrorSchema()->getErrors());` and see if there is anything unusual in there.

Comment: I have edit my post. There is link to this project. I add this var_dump($this->nform->getErrorSchema()->getErrors()); and this make an empty array

Comment: is there anything in the log showing errors on the submission of the form ?

Comment: No there is not. If you submit form with good data, there no error will rendering in template. This looks like a bind method doesn't work.

Comment: It looks fine. Can we see your template code as well?